# Connect to sql server from another machine

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2012

I want to Import/Export data from SQL Server in another machine (same network), to my machine. R doesn't recognise the SQLServer-DSN.

I have tested : `telned machine_IP SQLServerPort`. And it succeeded.
I have activated the TCP/IP in the SQL Configuration.
I have added an new DSN in the SQLServer machine.

My questions are :

1. Do I need an sql server in the R-machine to do : `R--> SQL ServerA --> Network --> SQL ServerB`. Or can I just do : `R --> Network --> SQL ServerB` ?
2. Do I need an R Server to connect sql server DB  to RStudio ?

I succeed to connecting R and SQL Server in the same machine, but not in two machines.

Comment: Looks like you have enabled firewall on machine B

Comment: I dont think so, because I added a rule to enable the flow on the port 1433.

Comment: Then check also if the sql server browser service is enabled on machine B.

Comment: sql server browser is running, Agent sql server is running too. I think that I missed a step : (Do I need to add something in the R machine (I have installed RODBC package, connect to database). Maybe the call to database lack some other information? the error that I get is that R didn't find the DSN and the name of the pilot isn't specified.

Comment: in R console : odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server}; server=servername\\\\MSSQLSERVER,1433;database=DatabaseName;trusted_connection=true) -->Error : Connection delay expired

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string you are missing one semicolon here:

```
odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server}; server=servername\\\\MSSQLSERVER,1433;database=DatabaseName;trusted_connection=true‌"​)
                                                                        ^ Should be an semicolon
```

Try this one:

```
odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server}; server=servername\\\\MSSQLSERVER;1433;database=DatabaseName;trusted_connection=true‌"​)
```

Or this one:

```
odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server}; server=servername;1433;database=DatabaseName;trusted_connection=true‌​")
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake, but now I get : SQL Server doesn't exist or its access is refused.

Comment: Have you tried to connect through the ip? You also should check if the mixed authentication is enabled.